# Connection Refused by Google Speech Recognition

Tags: python, connection, speech-recognition

I want to use SpeechRecognition in Python, and after installing all the requirements when I try it out with `python -m speech_recognition`, these messages came out:

```
A moment of silence, please...
Set a minimum energy threshold to 384.82495236781006
Say something!
Got it! Now to recognize it...
Uh oh! Couldn't request results from Google Speech Recognition service;
recognition connection failed: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

So what is this Error mean? How can I fix it? Many thanks
I'm using MacOS Catalina and Python 3.7.7

Comment: What python version and what OS?

Comment: Python 3.7.7 and MacOS Catalina

Answer (score -1):

You exceeded the usage limits probably. You can try to use other open source services, they are even more reliable and you can run them locally.

Comment: according to this package (which just showed up upon a first Google search) there's a couple simple ones you can run offline: https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/

Comment: That one is NOT recommended actually, its pretty broken design.

Comment: I didn't take the time to look to deeply, but it looks like the resources it recommends as outside stt drivers aren't linked to the library. I'm sure OP could find a different library that links with the other engines recommended there. That's all I meant when I posted the link.

Comment: There aren't usage limits on the speech recognition package. There are only limits when you use google cloud.

Comment: There are limits for extensive usage, you can't recognize 1000 hours of speech with speech recognition.